# VSTO: Get long-term EntryID from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder query

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, mapi

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the **long-term** entry id from a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder` query.  I can successfully query the table, but the entry id is always the **short-term** entry id.  As I understand it, the short-term entry id has the potential to change from session to session.

Here's my example code that -- additionally -- gets the sender's address as well as the base columns:

```
Table table = folder.GetTable();
table.Columns.Add("SenderEmailAddress");
while (!table.EndOfTable)
{
  Row row = table.GetNextRow();
  string entryId = row["EntryID"].ToString();
  string sender = row["SenderEmailAddress"].ToString();
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to add an additional column, allowing me to query the long-term entry id?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to request the `PR_LONGTERM_ENTRYID_FROM_TABLE` MAPI property. Since it is not one of the OOM properties, you will need to specify its DASL name - `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66700102"`:

```
table.Columns.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66700102");
```

See [Columns.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.columns.add) on MSDN for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the item to get a long-term `EntryID` property value. Consider using the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method which returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid). Then you may retrieve the `EntryID` property value which should be a long-term `EntryID`.

Short-term entry identifiers are used primarily for rows in tables and entries in dialog boxes, whereas long-term entry identifiers are used for many objects such as messages, folders, and distribution lists.